# Get relative cell value using R1C1 notation

Tags: vba, excel

I'm beginner in excel VBA. Sorry it should be something very basic. My question is I need to get the value of a cell relative to the active or selected cell. So what I tried is as follows

```
 ActiveSheet.Range("P2").Select
  Dim s As String
 s = "=RC[-11]"
```

What my plan was to get the value at cell, which is 11 columns left to the active cell. By **s="=RC[-11]"** I know it will print as it is and its not gonna do any operation. But I tried to express that was my final end value. So how can I achieve that.

Comment: Use `Offset` function.

Comment: You need to assign that string to the ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
myRange.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-11]"
```

Where `myRange` is a variable covering the range of cells you want to assign the formula to in column e.g. from start row to end row e.g.

```
Dim myRange As Range

Set myRange = ActiveSheet.Range("P2:P10")
```

Just pay attention to the square brackets which determine if using absolute or relative cell references.

Comment: That formula could be applied to all target cells at once; no need for any loop.

Comment: @jeeped yes. Silly me. On mobile and stress thinking.